# Reshaping variables for keras LSTM

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I want to make LSTM that will learn on the text that I will provide. First, i created the function that would take training data.

```
def read_data(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        content = f.readlines()
    content = [x.strip() for x in content]
    content = [word for i in range(len(content)) for word in content[i].split()]
    content = np.array(content)
    return content
training_data = read_data(filename)
print("Loaded training data...")
```

After, i have a function to assign all the words number.

```
def build_dataset(words):
    count = collections.Counter(words).most_common()
    dictionary = dict()
    for word, _ in count:
        dictionary[word] = len(dictionary)
    reverse_dictionary = dict(zip(dictionary.values(), dictionary.keys()))
    return dictionary, reverse_dictionary
dictionary, reverse_dictionary = build_dataset(training_data)
vocab_size = len(dictionary)
```

Exmaple from dictionary variable would be `'the': 0, 'and': 1, 'to': 2,`
I found some sample code for the LSTM

```
# reshape X to be [samples, time steps, features]
X = numpy.reshape(dataX, (n_patterns, seq_length, 1))
# normalize
X = X / float(n_vocab)
# one hot encode the output variable
y = np_utils.to_categorical(dataY)
# define the LSTM model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(256, input_shape=(X.shape[1], X.shape[2]), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(256))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(y.shape[1], activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
# define the checkpoint
filepath="weights-improvement-{epoch:02d}-{loss:.4f}-bigger.hdf5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]
# fit the model
model.fit(X, y, epochs=50, batch_size=64, callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

I dont understand what do i have to do for the reshape. My seq length is 3 but how do i determine number of patterns and as i understand dataX should be vector of the words. When i do this `X = np.reshape(dictionary, (n_patterns, seq_length, 1))`, it outputs `cannot reshape array of size 1 into shape (775,100,1)`. Could you please help me what to do.

Comment: What do you mean by *assign all the words number*? Are those just integer indices of words?

Comment: Dictionary is : 'the': 0, 'and': 1, 'to': 2,

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that `dataX` in the sample code should not be replaced by `dictionary`, but rather by a list of `n_patterns` samples from the data, each of which should be a subsequence of length `seq_length`, the terms of which should be a one-hot vector of length `vocab_size`.

It is usual to make such a dataset in a way similar to this (adjust `seq_length`, and the third argument of `range` to taste):

```
seq_length=50
dataX=[]
dataY=[]
for i in range(0,len(training_data)-seq_length-1,3):
    dataX.append([keras.utils.to_categorical(dictionary[word],num_classes=vocab_size) for word in training_data[i:i+seq_length]])
    dataY.append(keras.utils.to_categorical(dictionary[training_data[i+seq_length]],num_classes=vocab_size))
```

You may also want to consider using a set instead of a counter for `build_dataset`, which would result in this function instead:

```
def build_dataset(words):
    dictionary = dict()
    for word in set(words):
        dictionary[word] = len(dictionary)
    reverse_dictionary = dict(zip(dictionary.values(), dictionary.keys()))
    return dictionary, reverse_dictionary
dictionary, reverse_dictionary = build_dataset(training_data)
vocab_size = len(dictionary)
```

Thus, putting it all together, your final code might be (with some adjustments to make it fit the LSTM):

```
def read_data(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        content = f.readlines()
    content = [x.strip() for x in content]
    content = [word for i in range(len(content)) for word in content[i].split()]
    content = np.array(content)
    return content
training_data = read_data(filename)
print("Loaded training data...")

def build_dataset(words):
    dictionary = dict()
    for word in set(words):
        dictionary[word] = len(dictionary)
    reverse_dictionary = dict(zip(dictionary.values(), dictionary.keys()))
    return dictionary, reverse_dictionary
dictionary, reverse_dictionary = build_dataset(training_data)
vocab_size = len(dictionary)

seq_length=50
dataX=[]
dataY=[]
for i in range(0,len(training_data)-seq_length-1,3):
    dataX.append([keras.utils.to_categorical(dictionary[word],num_classes=vocab_size) for word in training_data[i:i+seq_length]])
    dataY.append(keras.utils.to_categorical(dictionary[training_data[i+seq_length]],num_classes=vocab_size))

n_patterns=len(dataX)
# reshape X to be [samples, time steps, features]
X = numpy.reshape(dataX, (n_patterns, seq_length, vocab_size))
# reshape Y
y = numpy.reshape(dataY, (n_patterns, vocab_size))
# define the LSTM model
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(256, input_shape=(seq_length,vocab_size), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(256))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(y.shape[1], activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
# define the checkpoint
filepath="weights-improvement-{epoch:02d}-{loss:.4f}-bigger.hdf5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]
# fit the model
model.fit(X, y, epochs=50, batch_size=64, callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

Comment: I get an  error KeyError: 'Alice'(first word in the text) in the line dataX.append([keras.utils.to_categorical(dictionary[word],num_classes=vocab_size) for word in training_data[i:i+seq_length]]).